# Return list of values that match VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using an array formula to return the list of values that match a certain criteria. It's working successfully, but when using a VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH in the criteria, it is failing. I need to list out all the values that match a certain value on a different table. Can someone help me work out why/suggest a different solution?

Here's my formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TBL1[Goals],SMALL(IF(INDEX(TBL2[Status],MATCH(TBL1[Goals],TBL2[Goals],0))="Planned",ROW(TBL1[Goals])-ROW(Setup!$F$7)+1), ROW(1:1))),"Empty")
```

Sample data like this:

| Goals |
| --- |
| Goal A |
| Goal B |
| Goal C |
| Goal D |

Another sheet:

| Goals | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Goal A | Planned |
| Goal B | In Progress |
| Goal C | In Progress |
| Goal D | Planned |

Output needed:

| Goals |
| --- |
| Goal A |
| Goal D |

Comment: It would be better if you add some sample data and the output you expect in your question.

Comment: consider using the `Filter` function

Comment: @Sanu_012 Sure I added it, it seems pretty simple, just the combination of those two functions seems to not be working as expected.

Comment: Better [edit] your post & add some sample data from both tables along with the criteria, will help us to fix the issue !!

Answer (score 0):

##### Contiguous Columns

| Goals | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Goal A | Planned |
| Goal B | In Progress |
| Goal C | In Progress |
| Goal D | Planned |

```
=FILTER(TBL2[[Goals]:[Status]], 
       (COUNTIF(TBL1[Goals],
                TBL2[Goals]))*(TBL2[Status]="Planned"))
```

---

##### Non-Contiguous Columns

| Goals | Updated | Employee | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Goal A | 11/20/2022 | J. Schmoe | Planned |
| Goal B | 1/17/2023 | A. Baba | In Progress |
| Goal C | 1/19/2023 | T. Rock | In Progress |
| Goal D | 12/22/2022 | D. Town | Planned |

```
=FILTER(FILTER(TBL2[[Goals]:[Status]], 
       (COUNTIF(TBL1[Goals],
                TBL2[Goals]))*(TBL2[Status]="Planned")),
        {1,0,0,1})
```